# Minitest gives different results on two consecutive runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I've been playing around a bit with Minitest, and have found behavior that I can't seem to find an explanation for

I have a very simple model test file as follows:

```
require 'minitest_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobards", password_confirmation: "foobards")
  end

  describe "with admin attribute set to 'true'" do
    before { @user.toggle!(:admin) }

    it { @user.admin.must_equal true }
  end 
end
```

When I run this code for the first time after a 'rake db:test:prepare', the test passes

When I run it for the second consecutive time, it gives me an error:

> test_0001_anonymous                                       0:00:00.132 
>   ERROR
>           SQLite3::ConstraintException: column email is not unique: INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "created_at", "email", "name",
>   "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Yet this error does not seem to occur if I take out the

```
before { @user.toggle!(:admin) }
```

My minitest_helper.rb is as follows:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)
end

Turn.config.format = :outline
```

I can't seem to understand if this is a bug or if (more likely) I'm missing something.
Could someone more knowledgeable than me please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toggle!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle%21) method saves the record. So, when you run test for the second time, there are already one record with the email "user@example.com" in the database. And the validation which guarantees uniqueness of the email address fails.

Try to use [`toggle`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle)(without bang) instead.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Do you happen to know a good way to ensure a clean database/session before running tests with Minitest aside from calling rake db:test:prepare everytime? I feel like this wasn't as much of an issue with rspec..

Answer (score 1):

You need to either wrap each test in a transaction (and roll it back so that the changes are never saved) or clear out all the tables between tests. If not junk left from the database will interfere with subsequent test runs

The database_cleaner gem is one way of doing this and supports multiple strategies (transaction, truncation etc) for a range of ORMs